# Calling kmap_atomic() in process context

Tags: c, linux-kernel, scheduling, preemption

I have a kernel module. It has one IOCTL which allocates pages and then maps in to the kernel using kmap_atomic one page at a time.

When i run exercise this ioctl through a test app, i get the following scheduling BUG:

```
    [41216.007065] BUG: scheduling while atomic: app/1242/0x00000002
    [41216.007403] Modules linked in: allocator(O) gpu(O) [last unloaded: gpu]
    [41216.007910] CPU: 0 PID: 1242 Comm: app Tainted: G        W  O    4.10.0-rc5-00111-g49e555a-dirty #22
    [41216.008385] Hardware name: linux,dummy-virt (DT)
    [41216.008667] Call trace:
    [41216.008907] [<ffff000008088ba0>] dump_backtrace+0x0/0x23c
    [41216.009242] [<ffff000008088df0>] show_stack+0x14/0x1c
    [41216.009563] [<ffff000008375efc>] dump_stack+0x94/0xb4
    [41216.010318] [<ffff00000816bcb0>] __schedule_bug+0x58/0x6c
    [41216.010723] [<ffff0000088a9204>] __schedule+0x404/0x574
    [41216.011099] [<ffff0000088a93ac>] schedule+0x38/0x9c
    [41216.011454] [<ffff00000808873c>] do_notify_resume+0x90/0xa0
    [41216.011844] [<ffff000008083618>] work_pending+0x8/0x10
```

Does anyone know what is causing this?
In the kernel, this message is printed in kernel/sched/core.c
because the following check is true

```
    if (unlikely(in_atomic_preempt_off())) {
    __schedule_bug(prev);
    preempt_count_set(PREEMPT_DISABLED);
    }
```

this check is defined in include/linux/preempt.h

```
    /*
     * Check whether we were atomic before we did preempt_disable():
     * (used by the scheduler)
     */
    #define in_atomic_preempt_off() (preempt_count() != PREEMPT_DISABLE_OFFSET)
```

If this makes any sense to any person, please share your perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Between `kmap_atomic()` and `kunmap_atomic` **it is not permitted to sleep**.

From [Documentation/vm/highmem.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/highmem.txt):

> kmap_atomic().  This permits a very short duration mapping of a single
>        page.  Since the mapping is restricted to the CPU that issued it, it
>        performs well, but the issuing task is therefore required to stay on that
>        CPU until it has finished, lest some other task displace its mappings.